# How to use different fonts (ttf) on a 8×8 MAX7219 matrix, micropython and esp82266?

Tags: fonts, esp8266, micropython

I have been using a single 8×8 MAX7219 matrix with an esp8266 and micropython. I run it with mcauser's library (https://github.com/mcauser/micropython-max7219). It works as it should.

Instead of using the matrix's built in font, I want to use a font like this on the matrix: https://www.dafont.com/codi.font or https://www.dafont.com/eight-bit-dragon.font

I have seen people do it, but no explains how to.

Here is the code I am currently using to scroll text on this matrix:

```
import max7219
import time
from machine import Pin, SPI
spi = SPI(1, baudrate=10000000, polarity=0, phase=0)
display = max7219.Matrix8x8(spi, Pin(15), 1)
display.brightness(15)
display.fill(0)
display.show()

scroll_txt = "Matrix Scroll" 

output = scroll_txt
# scroll text
p = 1 * 8
        
while True:
    for p in range(1 * 8, len(output) * -8 - 1, -1):
        display.fill(False)
        display.text(output, p, 0, not False)
        display.show()
        time.sleep_ms(135)
```

Thanks,
Maheswar

Answer (score 0):

There's no "built-in" font on the display - the MAX7219 library that you're referring to, uses MicroPython's `framebuf` module to provide text handling. As you'll find [in the documentation for framebuf](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/framebuf.html#framebuf.FrameBuffer.text), you cannot change the font in this case.

> All characters have dimensions of 8x8 pixels and there is currently no
> way to change the font.

The [Awesome MicroPython list](https://awesome-micropython.com/) shows at least one other MAX7219 8x8 matrix library, I've checked that and it appears not to have the ability to modify the font either.

There are [various options](https://awesome-micropython.com/#fonts) for font handling but generally you'll be looking at doing a lot of the work yourself. Also, bear in mind that you're talking about an ESP8266, so memory for different character sets is going to be extremely limited.

I'd suggest looking at the code for the projects you've seen that achieve this - also confirm whether or not they are running on ESP8266 and that the matrixes are definitely MAX7219 and not an alternative such as ht16k33.